# Use of TABLE_DATE_RANGE function in Views

Tags: google-bigquery

I am excited about the new featured released earlier this week.

I went to create a view that Unions my "last 90 days" tables. such view can be very useful and simplifies any coding significantly. I used the new TABLE_DATE_RANGE function.

I wrote:

```
SELECT 
 *
FROM 
(TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mydataset.mytableprefix, 
                    DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -90, 'DAY'),
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()))
```

When running the query it runs fine, when I clicked "Save View" I got a red error message saying:

```
Failed to create view. Not Found: Table myproject:mydataset.mytableprefix
```

this happens also if use use specific fields instead of Select *.

Are there limits of usage of the TABLE_DATE_RANGE in views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Views didn't work with `table_date_range()` or `table_query()` for a long time. However, this was fixed as of this afternoon (2015-01-22).

Comment: Thanks, Looking forward to the resolution, this can simplify my project so much...

Comment: Jordan, any news about adding this functionality?

Comment: @Jordan `table_date_range()` is still not compatible with Views. Do you have any idea when this functionality will be implemented?

Comment: The fix for this was rolled out this afternoon.