# Can't create view from query that uses Table Wildcard function

Tags: google-bigquery

Seems to be a bug when saving views that contain TABLE_QUERY()

```
SELECT word FROM 
TABLE_QUERY(publicdata:samples, 'table_id CONTAINS "shakes"')
LIMIT 10
```

This query runs successfully but when I try to save as a view I get:

"Failed to create view. Table name cannot be resolved: dataset name is missing."

When I refer to the table name explicitly I am able to save the view successfully. e.g.:

```
SELECT word FROM 
publicdata:samples.shakespeare
LIMIT 10
```

Ultimately I'm trying to create a view that queries from a date-partitioned dataset. Any suggested workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

See [Use of TABLE_DATE_RANGE function in Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681475/use-of-new-table-date-range-function-in-new-views)

This is not yet supported; we realize it is an important use case however.