# How do I create a BigQuery View

Tags: google-bigquery

How could I create a BigQuery view via UI command or BQ command line?

I want to create a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW mydataset.myview AS
SELECT field1, field2 
FROM mydataset.mytable
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of new TABLE\_DATE\_RANGE function in new Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681475/use-of-new-table-date-range-function-in-new-views)

Answer (score 18):

1. Edit your query in the web UI
2. Choose "Save View" (near the "Run Query" button)
3. configure the name and dataset

...

Comment: I tried to create a view that way and it worked. But when I write the query with some complexity, it does not work: from
Select field1, field2 from (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydataset.mytable], Current_Timestamp(),Current_Timestamp()))   .. It complains that the table is not found when I try to create the view. But the Query works fine on the browser.

Comment: Unfortunately using TABLE_DATE_RANGE is not possible yet in BQ. See my linked duplicate for more details.

Comment: Note: Feature was implemented! https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions

Answer (score 9):

It looks like now is  supported the views creation through standard sql. It requires specify project, dataset and table/view name. For example

```
create view `myproject.mydataset.myview` as select * from `myproject.mydataset.mytable`;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bq` command-line option:

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `project-name.dataset-name.view-name` AS SELECT * FROM `project-name.dataset-name.table-name`';
```

Answer (score 1):

There're two ways of creating views in BQ.

Method 1: By Writing Queries

```
CREATE VIEW `projectid.datasetid.view_name` AS
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, ..
FROM `projectid.datasetid.table_name`
```

Note: If you run this view on the same project then you can omit projectid, you can mention datasetid.view_name. But if you run this view in other project then make sure to specify the projectid as well.

Method 2: Using GUI
Step 1: Write your Select statement
Step 2: Besides RUN button Save option will be there. Click on that dropdown menu and select "Save View" option to save your query as a view.
Step 3: Provide name to your view
Step 4: Check your dataset, a new view will get created.

Checkout this 1 hour BQ video, where you'll learn everything about BQ
https://youtu.be/MYAfyPlVVak