# View with parameters in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a set of events (kind of log) that we want to connect to get the current state. To improve performance/cost further, we would like to create snapshots (in order to not check all the events in history, but only from the last snapshot). Logs and snapshots are the tables with date suffix.

This approach works OK in the BQ, but we need to manually define the query every time. Is there any way to define 'view' with parameters (e.g. dates for the table range query)? Or any plans to do something like that?

I know that there are some topics connected with TABLE_RANGE / QUERY in views  (eg [Use of TABLE_DATE_RANGE function in Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22681475/use-of-new-table-date-range-function-in-new-views)). Are there any new information on this subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a great feature request - but currently not supported. Please leave more details at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list, the BigQuery team takes these requests very seriously!

Comment: Thanks! I added a request to the list: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=164

The second part is already in the list: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=96

Answer (score 7):

Now you can use **Table Functions** (*aka table-valued functions - TVF*) to achieve this. They are very similar to a view but they accept a parameter. I've tested and they really help to save a lot while keeping future queries simple, since the complexity is inside the Table Function definition. It receives a parameter that you can then use inside the query for filtering.

This example is from the documentation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION mydataset.names_by_year(y INT64)
AS
SELECT year, name, SUM(number) AS total
FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_current`
WHERE year = y
GROUP BY year, name
```

Then you just query it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mydataset.names_by_year(1950)
```

More details can be found in the [oficial documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions).

Comment: This is clearly the right answer, thanks for mentioning it here or I wouldn't have found it. @roland-plaszowski, can I please ask that you mark this answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround i wrote a small framework to generate complex queries with help of velocity templates. Just published it at https://github.com/softkot/gbq

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at BigQuery scripting that have been released in beta : https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting